# Uploading image issue in magento 1.9.3.1

Tags: php, image-upload, magento1.9.3.1

Before posting this question, I have made changes as describe in [Security-Patches/SUPEE-8788](https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/SUPEE-8788-Solutions-to-Different-Problems/m-p/52572#U52572).
After make changes as described, now "Browse" and "Upload" buttons appears but it is not working. When I click on upload button it shows some progress bar but it appears as progress shows upload completed, it not move to above images gallery, it's look like something is still broken. Please let me know if some one have fix this issue in magento 1.9.3.1

Comment: i had the issue with this patch break uploading in admin, cat you paste your browser console log errors for more details ?

Comment: You need to flush the cache then logout from admin.Now login into the admin. If the issue not resolve then clear browser cache or use private window.

Comment: I have the same issue. No custom admin theme. Flushed all cache in magento and browser - even tried a private windows. 1.9.3.1 has broken upload buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to follow the suggestions found here [SUPEE-8788-Solutions](https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/SUPEE-8788-Solutions-to-Different-Problems/m-p/52572#U52572), purging all forms of cache everywhere, and digging through lines of plugin code that had no effect on uploads, nothing helped. Then I stumbled on the suggestion to merge the Javascript code - this worked!

I am sure this is a multi faceted beast but this may help:

System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer

Turn on "Merge JavaScript Files"

[image: Merge js Files]

Answer (score 2):

**Fixed - Image Upload issue after PATCH 8788 install of Magento version CE 1.7.0.2 - 1.9.2.4.**

**`I was able to fix it,Please Follow following instruction.`**

> Step >> 1: After installed security patch 8788 successfully, Please go to admin panel and **flush all Magento cache**. Then **Logout your Admin Panel** and **Relogin to Admin Panel**.
>
> Step >> 2: **Go to Index Management** and select all **reindex all data** after **flush all Magento cache once again**.
>
> Step >> 3: ***This very Important step,*** **Delete your browser cache(Ctrl+shift+Delete) history clear all browsing data from browser including cookies.**
>
> Step >> 4: Go to Catalog >> Product Management , **add new image of any product,now you can see everything work fine.**

Comment: Very good ans, you  are right